# AS3: How to add child in a container?

Tags: actionscript-3, containers, addchild

I cannot sort this out few hours now ;(. I want to add a child in a container. This is what I have done so far. All the problems are in class Creator. This line par2.addChild(ship); //works, but this line par2.containerSDv.addChild(ship); //error:1119.

Thanks

```
    public class Main extends MovieClip
{
    private var containerSD:Container = new Container;
    private var ship:Ship2;

    public function Main()
    {
        // constructor code
        stage.addChild(containerSD);
        //ship = new Ship2;
        //containerSD.addChild(ship);

    }
}
```

.

```
    public class AddChild2 extends SimpleButton
{
    private var creatorche:Creator = new Creator;
    private var s:Ship2;

    public function AddChild2()
    {
        // constructor code
        addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onCLICK)
    }

    private function onCLICK(e:MouseEvent)
    {
        s = new Ship2;
        creatorche.onCreator(s, stage);
    }
}
```

.

```
    public class Creator extends MovieClip
{
    private var ship:MovieClip;
    private var containerSDv:Container = new Container;

    public function Creator()
    {
        // constructor code
    }

    public function onCreator(par1:MovieClip, par2:Stage)
    {
        ship = par1;
        //par2.addChild(ship); //works
        par2.containerSDv.addChild(ship); //error:1119
        ship.x = Math.random() * 200;
        ship.y = Math.random() * 200;
    }

}
```

.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might need to take a step back and re-evaluate your overall design and objectives.

consider this approach :

```
public class Main extends MovieClip
{
    private var container:Sprite = new Sprite;
    private var newShipButton:NewShipButton = new NewShipButton;
    private var creator:Creator;

    public function Main()
    {
        creator = new Creator;
        addChild(container);
        addChild(newShipButton);

        newShipButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, newShipButtonHandler);

    }

    private function newShipButtonHandler(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        // shipStyle would be a MovieClip of the artwork for a given ship.
        var ship:Ship = creator.makeShip(shipStyle, speed, power, container);
        ship.x = Math.random() * 200;
        ship.y = Math.random() * 200;
    }

}
```

Here's an example of a Creator class

```
public class Creator
{

    public function Creator()
    {
        // constructor code
    }

    public function makeShip(style:MovieClip, speed:Number, power:Number, container:MovieClip):Ship
    {
        var ship:Ship = new Ship(style);
        ship.speed = speed;
        ship.power = power;
        container.addChild(ship);
        return ship;
    }

}
```

I made a few assumptions such as you having a Ship class will extend a MovieClip/Sprite and has artwork, and that your NewShipButton class will extend SimpleButton and have artwork.

If this doesn't fit your needs, please explain what it is that you are trying to do that doesn't fit this extremely simple design.

I've seen a number of posts by you that seem to be making things far more difficult than they need to be. Maybe there is a good reason for that, but if so, please explain why the above approach will not work for your purposes.

Comment: Hello prototypical, thanks so much for your answer. My game is changing every minute. I am training my skills and learning while making the game. Your approach above is ok and works but I need to use my Creator class that functions are to display the passed object on the stage. I want to be able to pass any movieClip object to the Creator class and it will add some properties to the passed object (speed, size). I am not completely sure but this should be the Composition type of design.
However, everything works fine and I can add any passed object on the stage but not into the container.

Comment: Why can you not just call the creator class to give you a ship with the properties you desire ?

Comment: I've updated my answer. It now has a Creator class. You can see what I mean. You could even move the definition of the speed/power or whatever inside the Creator class, but this was just an example of what I am talking about.

Comment: Shoot me an email at prototype.in.training@gmail.com and I can help you far quicker than on here if you have gmail and we can chat.

Comment: Thanks prototypical, 
everything is clear now just one thing: You add the child from Main class, I am trying to do this from the Creator class. Am I wrong doing this way? What is the plus and the minus of your approach?

Comment: I just modified it. Honestly, it really depends on WHY you need to add it within the Creator. If there's a good reason, then do it.

Comment: For me personally, I like to add/remove children in the location where the container exists, which is in the Main class in this case. One advantage of doing it in the Creator is that it is one less line of code in Main. But.... someone reading your code in main, would not likely "assume" that you are adding the child to the container. Being explicit has it's advantages.

Answer (score 0):

If I give name to the Container and uncheck Strict Mode in Settings and my code works. I found very helpful article about the DisplayObjectContainer http://joshblog.net/2007/07/12/disabling-actionscript-3-strict-mode-in-flash-cs3/

```
    public class Creator extends MovieClip
{
    private var ship:MovieClip;
    private var containerSDv:Container = new Container;

    public function Creator()
    {
        // constructor code
    }

    public function onCreator(par1:MovieClip, par2:Stage)
    {
        ship = par1;
        //par2.addChild(ship); //works
        par2.getChildByName("contain").addChild(ship); //error:1119
        ship.x = Math.random() * 200;
        ship.y = Math.random() * 200;
    }

}
```

.

```
    public class Main extends MovieClip
{
    private var containerSD:Container = new Container;
    private var ship:Ship2;

    public function Main()
    {
        // constructor code
        stage.addChild(containerSD).name = "contain";
        containerSD.x = 0;
        containerSD.y = 0;


    }
}
```

Comment: If I leave everything as it is above and don't touch Strict Mode (ticked) I am getting error 1061:1061: Call to a possibly undefined method addChild through a reference with static type flash.display:DisplayObject

Comment: So, basically I think the compiler doesn’t know that my container is a dynamic object and I don't know how to tell this to it.